# Image file size on disk(KB) is getting increased upon the dynamic image resize(reducing size) in java

Tags: java, image, image-resizing, graphics2d, filesize

I'm new to Java. I resized the large sized png files to standard file size by maintaining the aspect ratio. Below is the code snippet that i used. But the downside i see in this code snippet is that,  after re-size the file size is much larger than the original. For e.g original is 5kb and the re-sized new one is 16kb.

Kindly help me in avoid this file size getting larger upon resize

```
 public void SaveImage(String imagePath, BufferedImage image) {
        try {
            BufferedImage bi = image;
            File newImageFile = new File(imagePath);
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", newImageFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    public BufferedImage resizeImage(final Image image, Dimension newDimension) {
        final BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(newDimension.width, newDimension.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        final Graphics2D graphics2D = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
        //graphics2D.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);

        graphics2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, newDimension.width, newDimension.height, null);
        graphics2D.dispose();

        return bufferedImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

PNG compression works something like this: it uses a predictor to predict a pixel value from previous values and 'zip' compresses the resulting delta changes. The more low frequency content is present in an image, the better PNG can compress it.

Resizing will change the content and might prevent the PNG predictors from detecting long runs which can be compressed better. Shrinking the image will enhance high frequencies which results in higher entropy which results in lesser dompression ratio.

Or it's just caused by the `ImageIO` writer, which might not set the best compression method for PNG. Have a look at `ImageWriter` and its `ImageWriterParam`. `ImageWriter` can be obtained by `ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(String formatName)`.

Comment: Note these images are being *resized* as opposed to *rotated*.

Comment: Post changed from 'rotate' to 'resize'.

Comment: Neet, No luck with ImageWriterParam. Any other options??

Comment: No, sorry. Just checked the PNGImageWriter by myself and it does not look to support any kind of compression setting. Maybe you can just use some command line utility to recompress the resized images in a second step (e.g. imagemagick's convert).

Comment: Looks like it is a [known bug](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6488522).  Interestingly, that page led me to [JAI-ImageIO](http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/) which provides an ImageIO plugin for PNG whose ImageWriteParam *does* support compression, but the library has the drawback of being part native library.